# RetroFit Android Bad POST request

Tags: android, api, rest, retrofit

I have POST API, i'm using retroFit in my android source code, this is API parameter in POSTMan
this is header:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ5Kg.png)

This is Body:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Gya.png)

Thisis my pseudo Code Android, API interface:

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers({"Content-Type: multipart/form-data", "Authorization: F31daaw313415"})
    @POST("api/store/order")
    Call<List<PostCommandResponse>> setCommandeProduct(@FieldMap Map<String, Object> test);
```

This is my Map

```
  data.put("product_id",productId);
            data.put("adress", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),adresse));
            data.put("city",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),city));
            data.put("zip",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),zip));
            data.put("first_name",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),surname));
            data.put("last_name",RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),lastname));
```

But always the response is 400 bad formated request.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use the data model class something like below.

```
public class UserInfo {

@SerializedName("product_id")
@Expose
private Integer productId;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("city")
@Expose
private String city;
@SerializedName("zip")
@Expose
private String zip;
@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String firstName;
@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String lastName;

public Integer getProductId() {
return productId;
}

public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
this.productId = productId;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

public String getCity() {
return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
this.city = city;
}

public String getZip() {
return zip;
}

public void setZip(String zip) {
this.zip = zip;
}

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

}
```

set the values in this model `UserInfo` and pass this to the API call something like below.

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: multipart/form-data", "Authorization: Bearer F31daaw313415"})
@POST("api/store/order")
Call<List<PostCommandResponse>> setCommandeProduct(@Body UserInfo test);
```

Just a small correction: also check if the **adress** or **address** is needed to be sent in JSON. **adress** is getting used in the JSON body image. Change accordingly.

**Edit**: you are sending the headers in the wrong format also.

It should be something like this.

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: multipart/form-data", "Authorization: Bearer F31daaw313415"})
```

Comment: Thank you for reply i tried data model also, but always same problem, my problem is in Header please check the image description of my header and tell me how to fix it

Comment: then i guess there is some issue in header the way you are sending. it should be in format "Bearer  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c"
something like this, you have to use dynamic JWT token not hard coded one as you are sending in code.

Comment: @SeekzApp check the edit might be you are missing the Bearer key in authorization headers

Comment: i pass bearer token in JAVA,                             .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)

Comment: if you have added an interceptor and headers there  then remove from the @Headers annotation from the api call method declaration. this might be overring the interceptor and sending wrong headers.

Comment: also if you want to add this to headers just add a Bearer key on front of JWT token separated by space

Comment: check in logs if the request is same as that of postman in correct format Bearer  <JWT token>

Comment: In postman it worked even i removed header annotation and just adding token in interceptor always same error 400

Comment: postMan response:

Comment: "id": 65,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "number": "65",
    "order_key": "wc_order_Dwxhf7xAYBpjk",
    "created_via": "rest-api",
    "version": "4.1.0",
    "status": "pending",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "date_created": "2020-05-26T07:52:54",
    "date_created_gmt": "2020-05-26T07:52:54",
    "date_modified": "2020-05-26T07:52:56",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2020-05-26T07:52:56",
    "discount_total": "0.00",
    "discount_tax": "0.00",
    "shipping_total": "10.00",
    "shipping_tax": "0.00",
    "cart_tax": "0.00" }

Comment: Android always reponse code 400, this is my request 
POST("api/store/order")
        Call<List<PostCommandResponse>> setCommandeProduct( @Field("product_id") Integer product,@Field("adress") String adress,@Field("city") String city,
                       @Field("zip") String zip, @Field("first_name") String first_name,@Field("last_name") String last_name);
JAVA header
 Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")